# A stable system of vector bundles can be obtained by pulling back the universal stable system

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

I am trying to solve the problem 180 on  [Davis-Kirk (p.269)](http://www.indiana.edu/~lniat/m621notessecondedition.pdf). However, the authors give some special definitions, so-called "stable system of vector bundles", which I have never seen on other literature. So I interpret the question in the following way.

(If you are interested, the definition is on page 263.)

Given a collection of vector bundles $\gamma_k:E_{k}\to B_k$ of rank $k$ such that we have the collection of bundle maps $g_k$ and $\tilde{g_k}$ such that the diagram commutes:

$\hskip2in$ [image]

Now, we have such a collection and the classifying maps $f_k:B_k\to BO(k)$ of $\gamma_k$. Then we have the diagram below, where the left face is commutative; the right, back, and front face are pull-back diagrams.

> We want to show that the bottom and top face commute.

$\hskip2in$ [image: cd]

I tried to use the universal property of pull backs and different ways of "diagram chasing", none of them work.